# Xcode showing "Ghost" header

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I couldn't find a better title to describe this problem. I created a UIView subclass called "ASFlyoutSheet". I added the class to another project (not copied, but referenced). After building the project many times successfully, I suddenly got some errors regarding duplicate headers. I checked out and I am sure there are no duplicates.

In order to investigate the error more deeply, I looked for the file (using the error link). The file is a GHOST! I can't find it in the project (see the image attached). I even removed the code from inside this header ghost, but still the error exists. I removed the original one from the project. Still the error exists. I cleaned. The erro exists. I finally created a file with the same class name, deleted it by removing to Trash, and still, this ghost header keeps on showing up.

[image: Ghost Header File]

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "svn repo"?

Comment: I usually see this kind of problem in Xcode when I have a subversion repository set up and delete a file without using 'svn rm'.  If you dont have a repo set up then I dont know what could be causing it.

Comment: Command-Shift-K cleans all targets, and can help resolving these kinds of issues.

Comment: @chown I don't know what you mean by using 'snv rm' and I delete files normally by hitting the delete button and moving the files to trash or removing references. I removed the project from the repository and still the same errors exist. I really don't know where this header is.

Comment: @MDT I tried cleaning several times with no luck

Comment: Well that's no good, and I don't use GIT or anything, but I believe "svn rm" is the official terminal command for properly removing a file from your repository.

Comment: I had to create a totally new project. Thanks for your help.